# Gem Load Error is: Node.js (V8) runtime is not available on this system

Tags: node.js, ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, passenger, execjs

I am deploying my rails app using Capistrano and nginx, when I try to view the app, it does not start, I get the error below, although when I do `which node`, I get this:

```
/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v8.0.0/bin/node
```

Although node is installed, the error is:

```
Gem Load Error is: Node.js (V8) runtime is not available on this system
```

If I run `ExecJS.eval "'red yellow blue'.split(' ')"` at `rails c` I get the expected result, so ExecJS already knows where node installed..

**EDIT**
`PATH` already contains the path for node

```
$ echo $PATH
/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v8.0.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

I am using Ruby without RVM.

More details:

```
age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:221 ]: Could not spawn process for application /var/www/my_app/current: The application encountered the following error: There was an error while trying to load the gem 'thredded'.
Gem Load Error is: Node.js (V8) runtime is not available on this system
Backtrace for gem load error is:
/var/www/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:71:in `from_environment'
/var/www/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:57:in `autodetect'
/var/www/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
/var/www/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/var/www/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/var/www/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/var/www/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/var/www/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/var/www/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/autoprefixer-rails-9.4.9/lib/autoprefixer-rails/processor.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/var/www/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/autoprefixer-rails-9.4.9/lib/autoprefixer-rails.rb:36:in `require_relative'
/var/www/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/autoprefixer-rails-9.4.9/lib/autoprefixer-rails.rb:36:in `<top (required)>'
/var/www/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/var/www/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/var/www/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/var/www/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/var/www/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/thredded-0.15.5/lib/thredded.rb:28:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
/var/www/my_app/releases/20190302100032/config/application.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
/var/www/my_app/releases/20190302100032/config/environment.rb:3:in `require'
/var/www/my_app/releases/20190302100032/config/environment.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
config.ru:3:in `require'
config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
/var/www/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-1.6.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
/var/www/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-1.6.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
config.ru:1:in `new'
config.ru:1:in `<main>'
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:101:in `eval'
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:101:in `preload_app'
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:189:in `block in <module:App>'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:380:in `run_block_and_record_step_progress'
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:188:in `<module:App>'
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably `/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v8.0.0/bin/node` is not in your `PATH` according to [`execjs`](https://github.com/rails/execjs/blob/master/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb#L135) source code. You could check `PATH` either from `shell` like `echo $PATH` or `rails console` like `ENV['PATH'].split(File::PATH_SEPARATOR)`. If your `node` path is not in your path then there are two ways.

Updating `PATH` or creating a symbolic link for your `node` inside `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin` directories because of the fact that they are default in `PATH`.

Comment: also, I can get into node using `/usr/bin/node` and `/usr/local/bin/node`, I've created symbolic links, but it does not help..

Comment: Is your `node` path inside `ENV['PATH']` when hit on production `rails console` or on wherever you have this issue?

Comment: yes, inside `rails c -e production` if I type `ENV['PATH']` I get the same result of `echo $PATH` at bash, which is `/var/www/dcaclab/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/bin:/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v8.0.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games`

Comment: Would you run this code and share the output on your production? `def node_exists?
  ["node", "nodejs"].find { |cmd|
    if File.executable? cmd
      cmd
    else
      path = ENV['PATH'].split(File::PATH_SEPARATOR).find { |p|
        full_path = File.join(p, cmd)
        File.executable?(full_path) && File.file?(full_path)
      }
      path && File.expand_path(cmd, path)
    end
  }
end`

Comment: thanks, I've executed it in production console, the result is: `"node"`

Comment: Would you restart your web server?

Comment: ah, yes, I restarted `nginx` the same issue.. it seems that its a matter of users permissions? I don't know why passenger can't see node..

Comment: Would you add the node path in `/etc/bashrc` file? This file is accesable from all users.

Comment: Then restart your server again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189316/discussion-between-zeitnot-and-simo).